# “Type Error: Can only join an iterable” Python error

Tags: python

When I try to add a student this error pops up. I have looked through many forms to find an answer and i can’t. I’m a beginner at python so I’m not the that good yet. Please help :) I’m making this for fun and to try get better. My goal is to be able to add students. And when needed I want to check the students name, grade and age. Nothing else.

```
import os

import time

class Student:
  stuCount = 0
  def __init__(self, name, grade, classroom):
    self.name = name
    self.grade = grade
    self.classroom = classroom
    Student.stuCount += 1

  def Info(self):
    print("Name:", self.name, "\nGrade:", self.grade, "\nClassroom:", self.classroom)

  def StuCount(self):
    print("Student count is", Student.stuCount)

def Commands():
  print("Type 'add' to add a student\nType 'view' to see the info of a student\nType 'x' to close\n")
student_names = []
student_info = {}


def Online():
  Commands()
  while True:
    command = input("> ")
    if command == "add":
      name = input("Name: ")
      age = input("Age: ")
      grade = input("Grade: ")
      student_info.update({"name": name, "age": age, "grade": grade})
      student_names.append(name)
    elif command == "view":
      view = input("Student Name: ")
      if view in student_names:
        get_info = student_info.get(name)
        print("Students info:", ", ".join(get_info))
      else:
        print("This name is not in our school")
    else:
      print("Unkown command")
        
            
        

while True:
  Online()
```

Comment: Note: Now looking at it I have no clue why I added the class so forget I added that.

Comment: `student_info` is not a collection of students; it always stores at most one name, one age, and one grade. Your `add` command overwrites whatever old student information you had with the new information.

Comment: As a result, `student_info.get` can return `None`, which is not an iterable value suitable for use with `str.join`.

Comment: You define a `Student` class, but never actually use it. Perhaps`student_info` should map names to instances of `Student`. (And `age` should be an attribute of `Student` as well.)

Answer (score 0):

After your code `student_info.update({"name": name, "age": age, "grade": grade})` is executed, the content of `student_info` will be `{"name": name, "age": age, "grade": grade}`.

So `student_info.get(name)` will only get `name`.

Also, this piece of code will throw an exception when the judgment is passed, because your variable name is not defined.

```py
view = input("Student Name: ")
if view in student_names:
    get_info = student_info.get(name)
```

You need to change `name` to `view`, or `view` to `name`.

Due to the use of [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#dict), when adding information with the same name, the previous information will be overwritten.

```py
def Commands():
    print("Type 'add' to add a student\nType 'view' to see the info of a student\nType 'x' to close\n")


student_info = {}


def Online():
    Commands()
    while True:
        command = input("> ")
        if command == "add":
            name = input("Name: ")
            age = input("Age: ")
            grade = input("Grade: ")
            student_info.update({name: {"name": name, "age": age, "grade": grade}})
        elif command == "view":
            name = input("Student Name: ")
            if name in student_info:
                get_info = student_info.get(name)
                print("Students info:", ", ".join(get_info.values()))
            else:
                print("This name is not in our school")
        else:
            print("Unkown command")


while True:
    Online()
```

Comment: This could be greatly improved by explaining what the problem is, and how this code fixes that problem.

Comment: @chepner You are right, I will make this a habit.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the get_info variable and use student_info in the join function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).